# Updating component data from an API call in a directive with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and ran into an issue.  I have created a simple angular app with a .net core web api backend and I am having issues updating the component data from a directive I made to handle mouse clicks.

What I would like to happen is when the mouse is clicked, a get request returns the data and updates the page.  I have read up on the the observer pattern and am using the 'rxjs' implementation.

This works fine for the initial page load, but when i click i would like it to send off another request and update the data on the page.  Any help would be appreciated!

This is the component Html I am testing with

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="testDiv" appApplyitemclick>
    <img src="######" />
  </div>
  <div class="ShowDiv" *ngFor="let stat of storedItem.statistics" >
    <p>{{stat.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my component TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ItemAPIService } from '../Services/item-api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.scss']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  public storedItem: Object = new Object();

  constructor(public ItemApi: ItemAPIService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ItemApi.GetItem().subscribe(x => {
      storedItem = x;
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my Directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import { ItemAPIService } from '../Services/item-api.service'
@Directive({
  selector: '[appApplyitemclick]'
})
export class ApplyitemclickDirective {

  constructor(private api: ItemAPIService) { }

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onMouseClick(event: any): void {

     // I WANT TO TO CALL THE API AND UPDATE THE PAGE HERE 
     // this.ItemApi.GetItem()
    }
}
```

Here is my simple web api service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemAPIService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  GetItem() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:1262/api/Item/get");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply inject the host component `ItemComponent` instance in the directive class `ApplyitemclickDirective` and refresh the data in the `storedItem` field :

```
export class ApplyitemclickDirective {

  constructor(private api: ItemAPIService, private host: ItemComponent) { }

  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  public onMouseClick(event: any): void {

    //call API and update the state of the host component
     this.api.GetItem().subscribe(data =>{
     this.host.storedItem = data;

    });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it when i get home from work.  I will mark it as answered if it works =)

Comment: Hi Amardeep, I injected this but still am not getting the data to be updated.  Does it matter that my directive is an attribute on a different component?

Comment: After merging my two components into one, this solution fixed my issue.  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a directive is the right path to take. You could just use a click [event handler](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding)

```
  <div class="testDiv" (click)="updateData()">
    <img src="######" />
  </div>
```

and move the `onInit` logic into a new `updateData` function (and call it from `onInit`).

If you really want to use a directive, I would still use an event handler - just add an output to the directive. You can event have the even emit the object result of the service request.